# How to configure elasticsearch 6 java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using Spring version 2.1.18.RELEASE (I can't change this version)
I need to implement a crud repository for elasticsearch, for this I connect spring-data-elasticsearch (version 3.1.21.RELEASE is automatically pulled up) with elasticsearch 6.4.3
I tried a bunch of manuals, but elastic is so different from version to version that I can't find a solution. I need to connect to remote server via https with username and password.

pom:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "path.to.elastic")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"path.to.elastic"})
public class ElasticConfiguration {

    private final int port = 1234;

    @Bean
    public Client client() throws Exception {

        Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "test")
                .put("xpack.security.user", "login:pass")
                .put("xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled", "true")
                .put("xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled", "true")
                .build();

        return new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
                .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("bah.elk1.com"), port))
                .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("bah.elk2.com"), port))
                .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("bah.elk3.com"), port));
    }


    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ElkThingRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Things, Long> {
        
    List<Things> findByEarNameAndName(String earName, String thingName);
}
```

Service interface:

```
public interface ElkThingsService {

    List<Things> simpleGet(String thingName);
}
```

Service impl:

```
@Service
public class ElkThingsServiceImpl implements ElkThingsService {
    
        private final ElkThingsRepository elkThingsRepository;
    
        @Autowired
        public ElkThingsServiceImpl(ElkThingsRepository elkThingsRepository) {
            this.elkThingsRepository = elkThingsRepository;
        }
    
        public List<Things> simpleGet(String thingsName) {
            return elkThingsRepository.findByEarNameAndName(AppInfo.SUBSYSTEM_CODE, thingName);
        }
    }
```

Things:

```
@Data
@Document(indexName = "things-*", type = "things")
public class Things {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String earName;
    private String name;
}
```

Now im get exceprion:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting [xpack.security.user] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings
```

When i add spring-data-elasticsearch 4.0.0 and try to use RestHighLevelClient i get `NoClassDefFoundError error creating RestHighLevelClient bean`

Comment: Documentation for the last 4.0 version can be found here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference. This version is long out of maintenance and support anyhow.

Comment: this version for spring boot 2.3